# Put their value on each edge of the graph

Tags: graphs

I have a graph made in latex and each edge (line of the graph) has a corresponding value.
How could I to put their value on each line of the graph, preferably close node that originates?

Below is my code.

```
% C(n,4) points of intersection
% Author: Hugues Vermeiren

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,intersections}
% 1) Represent n points on a circle
% 2) Draw the complete graph on these points 
% 3) Draw all the intersection points of any two of these segments
\begin{document}

\def\r{8} % Determina o tamanho geral do grafo
\def\n{9} \def\myangles{{36,72,108,144,180,216,252,288,324,360}}
 %This vector contains the angles detere mining the position of the points.
 %-----------------------------------------------------------
 % Variables and counters used to generate the 4-combinations
 \newcounter{np} \pgfmathsetcounter{np}{\n+1}
 \newcounter{na} \newcounter{nb} \newcounter{nc}
 \newcounter{ia} 
 \pgfmathsetcounter{na}{\n-1}    % saves some computations later
 \pgfmathsetcounter{nb}{\n-2}    % ""
 \pgfmathsetcounter{nc}{\n-3}    %   ""
 \newcounter{q} \setcounter{q}{0}    % if flag q=1 then exit the whiledo loop
 \newcounter{e} \setcounter{e}{0}    % e counts the combinations!
 \newcounter{a} \setcounter{a}{0}    % element of the 4-combination
 \newcounter{b} \setcounter{b}{1}    % ""
 \newcounter{c} \setcounter{c}{2}    % ""
 \newcounter{d} \setcounter{d}{2}    % ""

 \begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \fill[fill=blue!10!green!10!,draw=blue,dotted,thick] (0,0) circle (\r);
 \pgfmathparse{\n-1} \let\nn\pgfmathresult 

    % Determination of edges (lines connecting the nodes)

    % Homo sapiens
    % Edge Hs-Pt: 235
    \pgfmathparse{0} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[0]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[1]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[red,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Hs-Gg: 205
    \pgfmathparse{0} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[0]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[2]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[red,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Hs-Pa: 121
    \pgfmathparse{0} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[0]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[3]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[red,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Hs-Nl: 246
    \pgfmathparse{0} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[0]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[4]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[red,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Hs-Mm: 325
    \pgfmathparse{0} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[0]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[5]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[red,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Hs-Cj: 184
    \pgfmathparse{0} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[0]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[6]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[red,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Hs-Ts: 16
    \pgfmathparse{0} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[0]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[7]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[blue,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Hs-Og: 6
    \pgfmathparse{0} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[0]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[8]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[blue,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Hs-Mu: 1
    \pgfmathparse{0} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[0]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[9]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[blue,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});


    % Pan troglodytes
    % Edge Pt-Gg: 69
    \pgfmathparse{1} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[1]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[2]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[green,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Pt-Pa: 53
    \pgfmathparse{1} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[1]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[3]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[green,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Pt-Nl: 83
    \pgfmathparse{1} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[1]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[4]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[green,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Pt-Mm: 64
    \pgfmathparse{1} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[1]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[5]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[green,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Pt-Cj: 58
    \pgfmathparse{1} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[1]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[6]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[green,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Pt-Ts: 3
    \pgfmathparse{1} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[1]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[7]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[blue,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Pt-Mu: 1
    \pgfmathparse{1} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[1]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[9]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[blue,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});


    % Gorilla gorilla
    % Edge Gg-Pa: 66
    \pgfmathparse{2} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[2]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[3]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[green,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Gg-Nl: 66
    \pgfmathparse{2} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[2]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[4]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[green,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Gg-Mm: 81
    \pgfmathparse{2} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[2]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[5]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[green,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Gg-Cj: 72
    \pgfmathparse{2} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[2]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[6]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[green,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Gg-Ts: 3
    \pgfmathparse{2} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[2]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[7]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[blue,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Gg-Og: 1
    \pgfmathparse{2} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[2]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[8]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[blue,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Gg-Mu: 3
    \pgfmathparse{2} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[2]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[9]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[blue,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});


    % Pongo abelii
    % Edge Pa-Nl: 66
    \pgfmathparse{3} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[3]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[4]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[green,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Pa-Mm: 150
    \pgfmathparse{3} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[3]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[5]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[red,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Pa-Cj: 50
    \pgfmathparse{3} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[3]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[6]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[green,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Pa-Ts: 2
    \pgfmathparse{3} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[3]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[7]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[blue,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Pa-Mu: 2
    \pgfmathparse{3} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[3]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[9]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[blue,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});


    % Nomascus leucogenys
    % Edge Nl-Mm: 183
    \pgfmathparse{4} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[4]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[5]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[red,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Nl-Cj: 91
    \pgfmathparse{4} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[4]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[6]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[green,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Nl-Ts: 3
    \pgfmathparse{4} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[4]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[7]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[blue,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Nl-Og: 4
    \pgfmathparse{4} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[4]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[8]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[blue,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});


    % Macaca mulatta
    % Edge Mm-Cj: 158
    \pgfmathparse{5} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[5]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[6]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[red,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Mm-Ts: 7
    \pgfmathparse{5} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[5]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[7]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[blue,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Mm-Og: 5
    \pgfmathparse{5} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[5]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[8]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[blue,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Mm-Mu: 1
    \pgfmathparse{5} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[5]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[9]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[blue,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});


    % Callithrix jacchus
    % Edge Cj-Ts: 5
    \pgfmathparse{6} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[6]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[7]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[blue,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Cj-Og: 3
    \pgfmathparse{6} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[6]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[8]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[blue,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});

    % Edge Cj-Mu: 1
    \pgfmathparse{6} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[6]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[9]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[blue,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});


    % Tarsius syrichta
    % Edge Ts-Mu: 1
    \pgfmathparse{7} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[7]} \let\t\pgfmathresult % Start node
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[9]} \let\u\pgfmathresult % Destination node
    \draw[blue,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});




    % Determination of the nodes

    % Node Homo sapiens
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[0]}    \let\t\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathsetcounter{ia}{1}
    \fill[draw=blue,fill=blue!20!,thick]
        ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})circle (4.5mm) node{$\mathbf{Hs}$};  

    % Node Pan troglodytes
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[1]}    \let\t\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathsetcounter{ia}{2}
    \fill[draw=blue,fill=blue!20!,thick]
        ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})circle (4.5mm) node{$\mathbf{Pt}$};

    % Node Gorilla gorilla
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[2]}    \let\t\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathsetcounter{ia}{3}
    \fill[draw=blue,fill=blue!20!,thick]
        ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})circle (4.5mm) node{$\mathbf{Gg}$};

    % Node Pongo abelii
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[3]}    \let\t\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathsetcounter{ia}{4}
    \fill[draw=blue,fill=blue!20!,thick]
        ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})circle (4.5mm) node{$\mathbf{Pa}$};

    % Node Nomascus leucogenys
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[4]}    \let\t\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathsetcounter{ia}{5}
    \fill[draw=blue,fill=blue!20!,thick]
        ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})circle (4.5mm) node{$\mathbf{Nl}$};

    % Node Macaca mulatta
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[5]}    \let\t\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathsetcounter{ia}{6}
    \fill[draw=blue,fill=blue!20!,thick]
        ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})circle (4.5mm) node{$\mathbf{Mm}$};

    % Node Callithrix jacchus
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[6]}    \let\t\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathsetcounter{ia}{7}
    \fill[draw=blue,fill=blue!20!,thick]
        ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})circle (4.5mm) node{$\mathbf{Cj}$};

    % Node Tarsius syrichta
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[7]}    \let\t\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathsetcounter{ia}{8}
    \fill[draw=blue,fill=blue!20!,thick]
        ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})circle (4.5mm) node{$\mathbf{Ts}$};

    % Node Otolemur garnettii
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[8]}    \let\t\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathsetcounter{ia}{9}
    \fill[draw=blue,fill=blue!20!,thick]
        ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})circle (4.5mm) node{$\mathbf{Og}$};

    % Node Microcebus murinus
    \pgfmathparse{\myangles[9]}    \let\t\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathsetcounter{ia}{10}
    \fill[draw=blue,fill=blue!20!,thick]
        ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})circle (4.5mm) node{$\mathbf{Mu}$};



     \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{center}
     \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! It is great that you've added a complete example! However, there is quite a lot of it: could you make your example a little more minimal?

Comment: Every line of the form `\pgfmathparse{7} \let\ii\pgfmathresult % Start node` appears to do nothing, by the way, since you never use `\ii`.

Comment: I guessing, if you replace in your (not so M)WE `\draw[red,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})--({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});` with `\draw[red,very thick] ({\r*cos(\t)},{\r*sin(\t)})-- node[sloped,near start] {\u} ({\r*cos(\u)},{\r*sin(\u)});`, is the result close to what you looking for?

Comment: Hey Zarko, thanks for the suggestion. I will try to implement it as you taught me.

Answer (score 4):

Do you want something roughly like this?

[image: network]

I've specified the construction a little more concisely, I hope:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\begin{document}
% 1) Represent n points on a circle
% 2) Draw the complete graph on these points
% 3) Draw all the intersection points of any two of these segments
\def\r{8} % Determina o tamanho geral do grafo
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \fill[fill=blue!10!green!10!,draw=blue,dotted,thick] (0,0) circle (\r);
 \foreach \i/\m [count=\ino] in {36/Hs,72/Pi,108/Gg,144/Pa,180/Nl,216/Mm,252/Cj,288/Tc,324/Og,360/Mu}
 {
   \foreach \j [count=\jno] in {36,72,108,144,180,216,252,288,324,360}
   {
     \let\col\relax
     \ifnum\ino<\jno
       \ifnum\jno<8
         \ifnum\ino=1\def\col{red}%
         \else
           \ifnum\ino<4\def\col{green}%
           \else
             \ifnum\ino<8
               \ifnum\jno=6
                 \def\col{red}%
               \else
                 \def\col{green}%
                 \ifnum\ino=6\ifnum\jno=7\def\col{red}\fi\fi
               \fi
             \fi
           \fi
         \fi
       \else
         \def\col{blue}%
       \fi
       \ifx\col\relax\else
       \draw[\col,very thick] ({\r*cos(\i)},{\r*sin(\i)})--({\r*cos(\j)},{\r*sin(\j)}) node [pos=.2, fill=blue!10!green!10!, text=\col!75!black] {$\i$};
       \fi
     \fi
   }
   \fill[draw=blue,fill=blue!20!,thick] ({\r*cos(\i)},{\r*sin(\i)})circle (4.5mm) node{$\mathbf{\m}$};
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, this result it's very close that I want, but I need that each represented line on graph has a different value (different an each other).
For example, the node value Hs-Pt is 235; the node value Hs-Gg is 205, the node value Hs-Pa is 121 and etc....  These values are placed in comments above it's respective edge in the code.

Comment: If there's no pattern to it, then you have to specify each one. You could still use a loop, but it would obviously require many more values. If you prefer to keep your original code, you can add in the nodes as I have into each `\draw` command. `node [pos=.2, fill=blue!10!green!10!, text=<colour>!75!black] {$<value>$}` and just use the relevant values for `<colour>` and `<value>`. You can also adjust `pos=.2` to change the position of the node on the line to avoid clashes if you do it this way. (`.2` was a compromise which gave reasonable placement for most edges.)

Comment: Hi cfr, I managed to put the numbers on the edges, as your orientation.
Thanks a lot for the help!
You was essential for me to get to this graph.

Once again, thank you!